# Gnome Shell hiding Window Controls on Maximize

Tags: gnome-shell

Not finding the window controls where It used to exist is a very annoying thing. Only the Gnome Applications with actions in the title bar has this issue. Any pointers for debugging welcome.

Although not sure, I kind of believe that issues started after installing Something for Reddit from [Install Reddit Gnome App ‘Something for Reddit’ in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/10/reddit-app-something-for-reddit-ubuntu/). Could it be some problem with any dependency that came along with it?

Shell version is 3.24, Ubuntu 17.04

[When not Maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud1oE.png)

[When Maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3e7F.png)

Comment: You rejected the edit,i was trying to fix your link... so plz edit it yourself... is this the right link:   http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/10/reddit-app-something-for-reddit-ubuntu/

Comment: What happens if you use a standard Ubuntu theme?

Comment: @Sina, I cannot add more than 2 links owing to my lack of reputation. That is why I put it that way. Thanks for the concern! :)
And I edited the answer to add Shell and OS version and our edits conflicted. If you can edit it once again you're welcome!

Comment: @heynnema, Themes seem to have no effect on this whatsoever.

Comment: @Rahul.A.Krishna  When maximized, hold down ALT key, left-click in window, drag window to unhide controls. Otherwise, disable gnome-shell extensions and try again.

Comment: @heynnema, When the window is not maximized the Window Controls are there. I wanted them when they are maximized. 
I did disable the extensions but they had no effect too.

Comment: @Rahul.A.Krishna  Is it all applications, or just the Reddit app? Is it all user accounts, or just your user account? You could try uninstalling the Reddit app as per their instructions.

Comment: The apps like Files, Tweak Tool and everything having actions in title bar has the issue. 
Apparently, other user accounts don't have the issue. I hope you're on to something! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank You all! I removed the `.local/share/extensions` directory and things came back to normal. No idea what was causing the issue though!